# Error 462 Not Allowed

Tags: error, blocked-services

I'm trying to get onto lifewire.com and for some reason when I'm using Tor it throws up an 'Error 462 Not Allowed' page.

Anyone know why this is? The website is pretty vanilla not exactly NSFW.

Answer (score 1):

I can get lifewire through Tor by just running its link anonymously in Startpage.

For example: use DDG or Startpage and search on (w/out quotes) "lifewire.com". Click on Anonymous View for that https://www.lifewire.com result that shows up. Then you're in.  Then all resulting links in lifewire.com should run anonymously, at least as long as your session lasts.

Answer (score 1):

It seems they run a Varnish caching server in front of their page. The server tries to find out if someone connects over Tor and blocks this connection. I tried to use http://archive.is and to retrieve a copy of the website. This worked. So if you visit http://archivecaslytosk.onion/jBtl8 over Tor you can see the current version of the site.